Number of odd coefficients on the remainder of a polynomial division
I came across the following question a few days ago and I can't solve it no matter what I think:
Let $r(x)$ be the polynomial that is the remainder when dividing $x^{2050}$ by $x^5 + x^2 + 1$. How many odd coefficients does $r(x)$ have?
My last approach was using the fact that $x^{2050}\equiv(x^2+1)^{410} \,\,\mathrm{mod}\,\,(x^5+x^2+1)$ and tried to find some pattern for the powers of $x^2+1\,\,\mathrm{mod}\,\,(x^5+x^2+1)$.
Does anyone could help me with a tip to solve this one? I feel like there's some theorem or trick that I don't know or don't recall.
Thanks! ;)

When you say "odd coefficients", I assume you're asking how many non-zero coefficients there are on odd degrees, not how many of the coefficients happen to be odd numbers. Right?

The way the question is written in portuguese leads me to think it is asking for how many of the coefficients happen to be odd numbers. But I am not sure about that. Either way, I am open for suggestions!

To find which coefficients are odd in the remainder, just work in $\mathbb F_2$.  Additionally you may be able to quickly note $x^{2^5-1}=x^{31}\equiv 1$...

Thank you @Macavity!! I'll try this! ;)
